# Enable/Disable Item based on the value of the List Item

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I am trying to code a listItem which will have 2 values "New" and "Edit". I also have a search (Push Button) in the same canvas.  I want to disable the Search button when I have selected "new" in the list item and enable it when "Edit" is selected in the list item.

Here is my code :  I am using Oracle Forms 6i , WHEN_LIST_CHANGED Trigger ..

```
begin
    if :CONTROL.LI_DO='New' then
          go_item('PB_SEARCH');
          SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('PB_SEARCH',enabled,property_false);
    else if :CONTROL.LI_DO='Edit' then
          go_item('PB_SEARCH');
          SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('PB_SEARCH',enabled,property_true);
    end if;
    end if;
end;
```

Any help is appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

Been a while since I did forms, but can you disable an item that has current focus?

I.e. navigate (GO_ITEM) to another item then try to disable PB_SEARCH.

Answer (score 0):

```
LI_DO.Functional."Elements in List" : New (value 0), Edit (value 1);
LI_DO.Data."Data Type" : Number;
LI_DO."Initial Value" : 1;
LI_DO.Required : "Yes";
```

After those regulations, you may use the code below for "WHEN-LIST-CHANGED";

```
begin
    if :CONTROL.LI_DO = 0 then
        --go_item('PB_SEARCH');
          SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('PB_SEARCH',enabled,property_false);
    --else if :CONTROL.LI_DO = 1 then
    elsif :CONTROL.LI_DO = 1 then
        --go_item('PB_SEARCH');
          SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('PB_SEARCH',enabled,property_true);
    end if;
    --end if;
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to know the concept of using enabled property.
The following blog illustrate this with an example clears the point of misunderstanding of using 'enabled'property alone.

[Pls. follow the solution steps you should be familiar with the four required properties in co-ordinate with each together to enable and disable an item](http://oracledevelopertrainingtasks.blogspot.com.eg/2015/06/setitemproperty-enabled-true-or-false.html)